# Setting style.display from asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using a Panel in an ASP.NET webpage to hide or display a selection of control in response to a client side button click. Simple script toggles the visibility

```
<script>
    function SetToAddSurvey() {

    var x = document.getElementById("NewSurveyPanel");
    if (x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I now need to toggle the display property on the server side following a database transaction. I know I can't use the code

```
NewSurveyPanel.visible = false;
```

as it will cause the control to not be rendered and the above jscript to fail when it is called next.

```
NewSurveyPanel.Attributes["display"] = "block";
```

also doesn't work.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Ta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CSS class:

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

....

```
 NewSurveyPanel.CssClass = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
NewSurveyPanel.Attributes["style"] = "display: none";
```

or

```
NewSurveyPanel.Attributes["style"] = "visibility: hidden";
```

What this does is to render the opening tag like this:

```
<div ....... style="display: none" ....>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code Behind**

```
NewSurveyPanel.Attributes["style"] = "display: block";
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Panel ID="NewSurveyPanel" runat="server">
    test
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="SetToAddSurvey(); return false;" />
<script>
    function SetToAddSurvey() {

        var x = document.getElementById("<%= NewSurveyPanel.ClientID%>");
        alert(x);
        if (x.style.display == "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```